# File Rename Function on Microware OS-9

Tags: file-rename

Is there a system call (C API function, not assembler) to rename a file in [Microware OS-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-9) 3.03?

If not, is there an accepted way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second part:  I worked around this by doing an open on the file.  If the open succeeded then I infer the file exists.  If the open failed then I check the error in errno.  If it's EOS_PNNF, then I infer the file does not exist.  Anything else is an error.

I would still like to know about the first part of the question.